# Put <li> at the bottom of the Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu where I have two `<li>` tags, "Login" and "Register":

[image]

And I want to put them at the bottom.

Where is the code for the menu.

```html
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
<nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#top" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>A Dog O</a></li>
    <li><a href="#top" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sobre" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Sobre</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown" runat="server">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" runat="server">Serviços<span id="Span1" class="caret" runat="server"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-dropdown-in="fadeInUp" data-dropdown-out="fadeOutDown">
        <li><a href="#">Saúde</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Escola</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Qql coisa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Coisa qql</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Contactos</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.aspx" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>LogIn</a></li>
    <li><a href="signup.aspx" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Registar</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more simple!

`<li style="position: absolute;margin-top: <margin that u want>;width: 100%;">
      <a href="login.aspx" onclick = $("#menu-close").click();>LogIn</a>
      <a  href="signup.aspx" onclick = $("#menu-close").click();  $('#signupbox').show()>Registar</a>
</li>`

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can make that column `flex` with `flex-direction: column`, then wrap the buttons you want at the bottom in an element with `margin-top: auto` to move it to the bottom.

```css
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar-nav {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.loginSignup {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
<nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    <li class="sidebar-brand">
      <a href="#top" onclick=$ ( "#menu-close").click();>A Dog O</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#top" onclick=$ ( "#menu-close").click();>Home</a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#sobre" onclick=$ ( "#menu-close").click();>Sobre</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown" runat="server"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" runat="server">Serviços<span
                        id="Span1" class="caret" runat="server"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-dropdown-in="fadeInUp" data-dropdown-out="fadeOutDown">
        <li><a href="#">Saúde</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Escola</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Qql coisa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Coisa qql</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#portfolio" onclick=$ ( "#menu-close").click();>Portfolio</a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact" onclick=$ ( "#menu-close").click();>Contactos</a>
    </li>

    <li class="loginSignup">
      <a href="login.aspx" onclick=$ ( "#menu-close").click();>LogIn</a>
      <a href="signup.aspx" onclick=$ ( "#menu-close").click();>Registar</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: ok, I've tried your code... I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but I will upload the current result

Comment: @TheAndréGomes you have CSS that is interfering and you haven't included that in the question.

Comment: At this time, as you can see, the 'Close' (X) button is a lot larger and I have to scroll. The scroll part I've fixed already. Another question. Can I put them side by side? Thank you a lot @Michael you've already helped me a lot!

Comment: Ooh sorry about that...My bad :/. I'm using the bootstrap.css. Is this a big problem?

Comment: I added bootstrap 3 and 4 and it still doesn't reproduce your screenshot... https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/bRaKpj

Comment: thank you for your time @Michael Coker but the code from the other user works perfectly. Thank you for your patience :)